# UISlider track image that doesn't stretch

Tags: iphone, image, uislider

I'm trying to use a custom track image for a `UISlider` but it is an asymmetric image from one end of the slider to the other.

I have tried setting up my image with `leftCapWidth` and so on but this just makes it take a maximum stretch and then starts spreading out one pixel of infor across the slider.

I'd like an image that doesn't change at all when you move the slider.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: I've managed to temporarily get around the problem for now by creating a UIImageView and adding that to the view behind the slider.  I then set the trackimage for the slider to blank.

It's not ideal though :(

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this? I've tried using `[maxImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile]` which works but seems to place the thumb underneath the track images and has about 2px blank space on both ends of the slider.

Comment: If I was doing this now I'd do it from scratch as my own custom control. Possibly using PaintCode to draw it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to make the background of the UIslider custom ,make the UIslider as an IBoutlet

```
[yourslider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon0.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];



yourslider.minimumValue=1;
yourslider.maximumValue=10;

UIImage *sliderLeftTrackImage = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"yellow_bg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 9 topCapHeight: 0];
UIImage *sliderRightTrackImage = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"yellow_bg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 9 topCapHeight: 0];

[yourslider setMinimumTrackImage: sliderLeftTrackImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[yourslider setMaximumTrackImage: sliderRightTrackImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```